# Query returns SQL expression and not value from database?

Tags: linq-to-sql, casting

I have an integer column in my table in the database, and I want to select it but it give me exception that can't convert from int to string

Example I want to select `CategoryID` from `Category` table where `CategoryName="Cat"`

`categoryID` is int & `categoryName` is string

my linq query which I tried

```
string Category_ID = (from p in StaticVa.new_data_context.Categories
                              where p.CategoryName == Category_Name
                              select p.CategoryID).ToString();
```

It returned `"SELECT [t0].[CategoryID]\r\nFROM [dbo].[Category] AS [t0]\r\nWHERE [t0].[CategoryName] = @p0\r\n"`

Comment: can you plz post some short of code

Comment: Your current code will generate the SQL statement - it doesn't fetch any data yet! You need to call `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` or `.ToList()` on your expression to actually evaluate it (run the query against the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
int Category_ID = (from p in StaticVa.new_data_context.Categories
                              where p.CategoryName == Category_Name
                              select p.CategoryID).FirstOrDefault();
```

LINQ is trying to return a IQueryable of every id which matches the where clause, if you only want one you need to specify it as single or first

Comment: What happens if that `Category_Name` is not found in the database?? How do you assign a `null` value to your `int` variable???

Comment: @marc_s fair point, i guess i should have made that a nullable int though if its not there it does default to 0

Comment: @marc_s its or default not or `null` so `default(int)` is `0` not `null`

Comment: @marc_s interesting, i have a test app where it works, is the int field in yours a nullable?

Comment: Sorry - my bad - my test app was explicitly converting to `int?` - it works fine as you coded it! I wasn't aware that Linq-to-SQL would "automagically" convert a `null` from `.FirstOrDefault()` into a `default(int)` - thanks!

Comment: @marc_s no problem, its why i use `if (result == default(type))` as my check of whether a result was found instead of `result == null`

Answer (score 1):

```
(from p in StaticVa.new_data_context.Categories
                              where p.CategoryName == Category_Name
                              select p.CategoryID)
```

represents an expression, that when executed, will return a set of items.

so you say:

```
var catIds = (from p in StaticVa.new_data_context.Categories
                              where p.CategoryName == Category_Name
                              select p.CategoryID);
```

then you get the for first one (ie. force the above expression to be execute and start returning values) by:

```
int? Category_ID = catIds.FirstOrDefault();
```

you need the `int?` in case there is no first row returned in which case `FirstOrDefault()` will return a null.

However if you're sure it return *atleast one row* then you can say

```
int Category_ID = catIds.First();
```

And if you're sure it return *only one row* then you can say

```
int Category_ID = catIds.Single();
```

Comment: Your very first statement isn't entirely correct - this code **doesn't** return anything yet! It's just built up an expression, ready to be executed... but it will be executed **only** when you call `.FirstOrDefault()` or `.ToList()` on it